# Why won't this code render the questions and answers I input?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have QUESTIONS and ANSWERS both of which are lists and will each contain 3 strings. I have to render both in the terminal through the function `render_responses()`

I've tried the code shown below and my attempts were all seemingly unsuccessful

```
QUESTIONS = [
  'Please explain your Python, Django and Django Rest Framework experience.',
  'What is your favorite feature of Python 3 and when did you use it?',
  'What is the most annoying aspect of Django or DRF?'
]

# TODO: Add your answers
ANSWERS = ["I took 2 classes through university both which were taught in python.", "me", "bee"]

def render_responses(questions, answers):
  # TODO: Render your responses out to the console
  questions = QUESTIONS
  answers = ANSWERS
  if questions == []:
    return("There are no questions")
  elif answers == []:
    return("There are no answers")
  else:
    return(questions[0], answers[0], questions[1], answers[1], questions[2], answers[2])
```

the code compiles but only returns  < function render_responses at 0x7fa2b1942b70   > when i put print(render_responses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to note that in python, almost everything is an object. That includes functions. `render_responses` is a function object, and you print it on this line:

```
print(render_responses)
```

If you'd like to call the function instead, put parentheses after it and feed it its necessary arguments:

```
print(render_responses(questions, answers))
```

Comment: You're definitely right, but now it's telling me that questions and answers are not defined

Comment: put them in all caps

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling the function, you're just printing the name and some metadata about the function.

use

```
print(render_responses())
```